# How do I correctly install snipMate for vim?

Tags: vim

I have problems installing snipMate for gvim.

My `.vimrc` file has the obviously required line

```
filetype plugin on
```

The `$VIMRUNTIME/plugin/snipMate.vim` file is exectued when I startup gvim. I verified this with an `echo` statement in this file.

Interestingly, I can make it work with the following sequence:

Startup gvim and read an existing c-file

```
c:\> gvim x.c
```

Then, in Vim

```
:source $VIMRUNTIME/after/plugin  
:e!
```

Now it works, as it is supposed to. I have no idea why this could be. And I was
able to install snipMate on another machine without problems.

Comment: For people voting to close: consider reading [this discussion in meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25925/160504).

Comment: @Sidyll as this is not a question of vim functionality but rather a question of installation issues (of a plugin at that), it may be better suited on SU.  However, I generally agree vim questions belong here.

Comment: @RandyMorris Hmm, good point. I didn't even think about it, it just became automatic: "Vim questions with close votes" -> "post link to meta" :-) Ok if it gets moved there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you don't want to touch your `$VIMRUNTIME` folder. This has many
drawbacks, some consider the worst drawback being the fact that this folder will
be overwritten in Vim updates, and you'll lose everything silently. Also, it's
definitely not practical.

In your runtime path a "personal" directory should be included. In Unix et al
this directory is `~/.vim`. Looks like you're under Windows, so it might be
something like `$HOME/vimfiles`. You may want to check [`:h runtimepath`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'rtp')

If you don't have that folder, create it and put your plugins there. The
structure is the same from `$VIMRUNTIME` and is described in the very same help
topic.

Note that the *snipMate* plugin require many other files to be included in your
installation. After you unzip (manually) the archive, place each of those
folders in your Vim folder, or just the files if the folder already exist. It
will end up being something like this (in my case, the folder is *.vim*):

```
.vim
  ├ after
  │  ├ plugin
  │  └ snipMate.vim
  ├ autoload
  │  └ snipMate.vim
  ├ doc
  │  └ snipMate.vim
  ├ ftplugin
  │  └ html_snip_helper.vim
  ├ plugin
  │  └ snipMate.vim
  ├ snippets
  │  ├ _.snippets
  │  ├ c.snippets
  │  ├ objc.snippets
  │  ├ ...
  │  ├ sh.snippets
  │  └ vim.snippets
  └ syntax
     └ snippet.vim
```

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you to take a look at a "modern" way of installing Vim plugins:

- [pathogen](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332)
- [vundle](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3458)
- [vim-add-on-mananger](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2905)

Personally I use pathogen but I think the other two plugin are fine too. Certainly, I would gid into vim runtime paths to understand better what it's going on but I can't imagine to deal with all my plugins without one of this tools.